# Does the Pixel Bender with Flash would use the GPU?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, pixel, pixel-bender

I write a Pixel Bender kernal for my flash.

I know that the pbk would run in another thread.

But when I run my swf, the GPU usage shows 0%.

I want to know does the Pixel Bender with Flash would use the GPU.

Comment: What do you monitor GPU usage with by the way?

Comment: Use the EVEREST, which is powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe say this about the GPU in Flash Player 10.1:

"The desktop player still uses software rendering for this release."

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS948100b6829bd5a6-54120f1012593d8f030-8000.html

Also see this:
http://www.kaourantin.net/2008/05/adobe-pixel-bender-in-flash-player-10.html

It's a little old, but I believe it still to be true.

Answer (score 0):

As Joony says, PixelBender does not (currently, 2010) use the GPU. But it does run multi-threaded, not just in a different thread. On a multi-core machine (almost all, nowadays) this is still a big performance boost if you need to do a lot of independent computation. ActionScript can only (currently, 2010) run on one thread, while PixelBender can use lots.

Answer (score 0):

March 2011 update: the new Flash Player 11 (Molehill) APIs are GPU accelerated. You can use PixelBender3D [1] in combination with the Program3D class [2] to get GPU acceleration with a software fall-back for incompatible machines.

Notes: PixelBender3D is an update of PixelBender. Also, this will only work with FP11 and not FP10.

1. http://blogs.adobe.com/pixel-bender/2011/03/03/pixel-bender-3d-public-beta-now-available/
2. http://labs.jam3.ca/asdocs/incubatorAsDoc/flash/display3D/Program3D.html